# JQuery regex not removing class until 3 characters deleted

Tags: jquery, regex

Hey guys I put up [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qQvt9/) so you know what I'm talking about since its a bit hard to explain. This JS is using a simple regex `/[1-9][0-9]{3}/` to detect a 5 digit number 10000-99999. This works ok and after inputing 5 digits in this range the color turns to green, otherwise the color stays on red. The issue is when "deleting" character after 5 digits is reached, the color does not return to red like it should but instead stays green until only two characters are left. I'm trying to fix this but am not sure why this is happening? help would be appreciated.

here's the Jquery for this.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function ()
    {
        $('#invoice').keydown(function()
        {
            var regex = /[1-9][0-9]{3}/;
            if (regex.test($('#invoice').val()))
            {
                $('#invoice').css({'color': '#0f0'}).addClass('valid-short');
                $('#path').val('check');
            } else {
                $('#invoice').css({'color': '#f00'}).removeClass();
                $('#path').val('update');
            }
        });
    });
</script>

<ul>
    <li>
        <label for='invoice'>Invoice</label>
        <input type='text' name='invoice' id='invoice' autofocus='autofocus' />
        <input type='hidden' name='path' id='path'autofocus='autofocus' required='required' />
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: so this is the exact format you need to accept? `10000-99999` where the first hyphen needs at least a 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this code instead:

```
   $(document).ready(function ()
        {
            $('#invoice').keyup(function()
            {
                var regex = /^[1-9][0-9]{4}$/;
                if (regex.test($('#invoice').val()))
                {
                    $('#invoice').css({'color': '#000'}).addClass('valid-short');
                    $('#path').val('check');
                } else {
                    $('#invoice').css({'color': '#f00'}).removeClass();
                    $('#path').val('update');
                }
            });
        });
```

Changes:

1. Uses keyup instead of keydown for fixing your bug.
2. Uses a regex that is actually correct. Your original regex (as well as some of the
   answers) allows some buggy numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are using `$.val()` to check the value of the input. BUT the value of the input is NOT set until after the `keyup` event.

So use: `keyup` event instead `keydown`

Besides that, your regexp is JUST fine:

- expression valid starting with 5 characters
- expression not allowed to start with 0

Answer (score 0):

.keyup will work better than keydown. Also, use this as your regex:

```
var regex = /\d{5}/;
```

Comment: `\d` will accept any integer and not require you to prepend with one or greater.

Comment: I think this will also match 00000 or 00101, I think it is required to only match numbers greater or equal 10000

Comment: Though .keyup is still needed.

Answer (score 0):

`/[1-9][0-9]{3}/` will match four-digit-numbers, if I am not mistaken. The first [] matches the first digit, the second [] matches the second, third and fourth digit. Try using `/^[1-9][0-9]{4}$/` instead.

Edit: Another way would be to not use regex and use something like this:

```
var val = $('#invoice').val();
if(val >= 10000 && val <= 99999) {

}
```

That should be faster than using regex.

Comment: This allows numbers like 99999999.

Answer (score 0):

the regex clearly matches 4 digits, not 5!

Even though I do not know JQuery, I'm pretty sure that the value of the text-field changes **AFTER** the keydown-event happens.

Therefore it matches correctly when the fifth digit is entered and behaves strangely when you remove digits.

Regards,

AKDA